# How to check query confirm

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to made  login script, but I stopped at the validation of input values. Here is my html code form login.php:

```
<form method="post" action="loginpro.php">
Username:
<input id="field" type="text" name="username" required>
User email:
<input id="field" type="text" name="email" requerid>
Password:
<input id="field" type="password" name="password" required>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

And this is my loginpro.php file:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== '' && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !== '' && isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== ''){
require("../admin/libsec/connect.php"); 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashed_passoword = hash('sha384', $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' AND email = '{$email}' AND password  '{$hashed_passoword}';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
// How to check if is query good so i can set session or if is not good to redirect to another page?
}
?>
```

Comment: It's so nice of you to allow SQL injection. A username of `admin' --` would log me in as the user "admin" without knowing the password. Thanks! (Psst, you have to escape your variables or use prepared statements and bind your variables!)

Comment: I know i must use mysqli_real_escape_string and i will but first i want to solve this problem

Comment: sanitize your inputs by using prepared stmnts, and check `if number of rows > 0` of that query then allow it otherwise not

Answer (score 1):

You could use `num_rows()` in this case to see if your query yielded rows:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(
    (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== '') && 
    (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !== '') && 
    (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== '')
){

    require("../admin/libsec/connect.php"); 
    $username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $hashed_passoword = hash('sha384', $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' AND email = '{$email}' AND password = '{$hashed_passoword}';    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    // How to check if is query good so i can set session or if is not good to redirect to another page?

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // user found
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else {
        // redirect the user back to login
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Sidenote: By the way, since you're using mysqli, why not utilize prepared statements.

Comment: I tried but it showed me this Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in blablabla...\loginpro.php on line 17

Comment: @fr33jumper the mysqli_query failed, use `echo $query` and run in in phpmyadmiin to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your usernames are unique you'll get back either one or no result rows.
If you didn't get one, the credentials are wrong, if your result has one line they were right.

And don't use string concatenation to create SQL queries! This is a big security risk. Habe a look at [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.